# Picking rows in SAS based on a specific value in a specific column

Tags: if-statement, sas

So I'm working with a data set that has millions of rows. I'm trying to cut down the number of rows, so that I can merge this data set and another data set by zipcode.

What I'm trying to do is take a specific column "X6" and search through it for the value of "357". Then every row that has that value I want to move into a new data set.

I'm assuming that I'm going to have to use some form of if/then statement, but I can't get anything to work successfully. If needed I can post a snapshot of some of my data or what SAS code I currently have. I've seen other things that are similar, but none of them involve SAS.

Thanks for all of your help in advanced.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Proc SQL to create your data set, then reference the value your looking for in your query -

```
Proc SQL;
Create table new as
Select *
From dataset 
Where x6 = 357
;
Quit;
```

Assuming your x6 variable is numeric...

On a mobile device...sorry for no code text

Answer (score 3):

RamB gave a great way to parse into two datasets. 
If you just want a new dataset that is a subset of the original, the following will work well

```
 DATA NEW;
      SET ORIGINAL;
      IF X6="357";   *NOTE: THIS ASSUMES X6 IS DEFINED AS CHARACTER*
 RUN;
```

A nice function can also parse multiple criteria. Say you wanted to keep records where X6 = 357 or 588.

```
 DATA NEW;
      SET ORIGINAL;
      IF X6 IN("357","588");   *NOTE: THIS ASSUMES X6 IS DEFINED AS CHARACTER*
 RUN;
```

Lastly, the NOTIN also works to exclude.

Comment: That's brilliant, because I want to do x6=357,354,351 and 348!

Comment: Nice! Consider using where instead of if, if speed is an issue

Answer (score 2):

With data step this is really simple. I'll give you an example.

```
data dataset_with_357
     original_without_357;
set original_dataset;

if compress(x6) = "357" then output dataset_with_357;
else output original_without_357;
run;
```

As I said, there are several ways of doing this, and it wasn't clear for me which is better for you.